# Segmentation of 3D mesh and feature extraction

Tags: python, 3d, projection, 3d-mapping, pymesh

I have five pictures of wound models taken from different angles links for the pictures is provided [here](https://postimg.cc/gallery/Zh0gK0K)

I have used [SFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion) for computing a mesh , the picture of the mesh is presented below [image]. I would like  to extract only the features associated with the wound region compute volume and depth accordingly.

In order to solve this question, i have used U-Net segmentation to generate a 2D mask of the wound from 2d pictures , an example of 2D mask generated using U-Net is shown below  [image].

I would like to know how i can map this mask onto 3D mesh and extract specific region within the 3D mesh which deals with wound part while removing other regions.

Any other ideas on how to segment the 3D mesh and extract specific region of interest are greatly appreciated, since i don't have different wound models i cannot apply supervised learning using 3D U-Net.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image and mesh to numpy array and follow the steps:

1. Duplicate the 2D mesh and stack it to make it a 3D mesh. for example, like this:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
mesh = np.array(mesh)
mesh = resize(mesh, (HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))
mesh3D = np.array([mesh]*3).reshape(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3)
```

2. Convert the pixel value of the mesh to binary (0,1). Set the part of the mesh where the wound is present to 1 and the rest to 0.
3. Multiply the mesh with the image.
4. Part of the mesh where the value is 1, that part of the image will remain as it is and the part of the mesh where the value is 0, that part of the image will be set to 0

Comment: I tried reshaping and i get a value error : ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3686400 into shape (512,512,3), I have chosen HEIGHT , WIDTH to 512

Comment: @DevanDev you will have to resize your image first, then you will be able to reshape it

Comment: I have done that using cv2.resize but still i get same value error : ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3145728 into shape (512,512,3)

Comment: @DevanDev I have added a way to resize, check it out

Comment: My mesh file is in .obj and its a 3D mesh and i am using trimesh to read my mesh file as     mesh = trimesh.load ('/home/Downloads/OneDrive_1_12-20-2021/texturedMesh.obj') , why should i duplicate my mesh in this case

Comment: @DevanDev save the mesh as jpg or png at the perspective of the mask, and then load the mesh as a numpy array and follow the steps

Comment: Can't we map the 2D mask region onto 3D mesh without performing the stacking it, i say this because when i try your approach it fails badly, my algorithm actually creates a 3D mesh in .obj file format

Comment: @DevanDev I don't know any other way.